# ScriptManager ServiceReference in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, master-page, wcf, ajax, listdata.svc

I have always used jQuery.ajax to retrieve data from listdata.svc or lists.asmx in SharePoint and from some custom web services. Now I will try Microsoft Ajax Library and especially [ServiceReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.servicereference.aspx) in ASP.NET which can be added to ScriptManager. Then javascript proxy should be created automatically.

Here is my ServiceReference in the masterpage:

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" 
  EnablePageMethods="false" 
    EnablePartialRendering="true" 
  EnableScriptGlobalization="false" 
    EnableScriptLocalization="true">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="/_vti_bin/lists.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

When I try this I get the 401 error:

```
GET http://dev/_vti_bin/lists.asmx/jsdebug 401 (Unauthorized)
```

[image]

Has anyone tried ServiceReference in SharePoint?

**EDIT (2012-02-20)**: I want to call [a custom wcf like Wictor Wilén](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Calling-a-WCF-Service-using-jQuery-in-SharePoint-the-correct-way.aspx). It works very well with jquery ajax. My custom.svc file is:

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Debug="true" 
    Language="C#" 
    Service="Takana.WCFService,Takana, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0c0327f8b01d9792" 
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

I tried to replace with [a simple .NET example](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html), with no success:

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Debug="true" 
    Language="C#" 
    Service="Takana.WCFService" 
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service needs to be AJAX enabled to generate a javascript proxy for you. Lists.asmx is not AJAX enabled.

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1), WebService(Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/")]
public class Lists : GenericService, ISoapServiceLists, ISoapServiceListData, ISoapServiceListSchema, IListSoapServiceContentTypes
{
}
```

For more information see [Understanding ASP.NET AJAX Web Services](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services)

Comment: You are right, but when I add my custom wcf service as reference, it doesn't generate any javascript proxy.

Comment: You have to make sure you properly configure your custom WCF to auto generate a javascript proxy as well. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628467.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628607.aspx for more information.

Comment: Have you used it with SharePoint, Rob? I just doesn't work here. I added namespace to my contract, added the stuff to web.config. I just wonder if this problem is just sharepoint-related.

Comment: Yes. This blog post series - http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/deploy-a-custom-wcf-into-sharepoint2010-part-1/ - has more information. Perhaps it will help. The only thing you might need to change is the security on the service binding. If your SharePoint development machine is running Windows 7 then you'll probably need to use Windows authentication rather than Ntlm.

Answer (score 2):

Dare i ask why you wouldn't just use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) (created by @sympmarc), an open source jQuery plugin that wraps methods in the OOTB SharePoint Web / WCF Services, making the use of these services in JavaScript as simple as the following [example](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Or a straight SharePoint object model call with JavaScript, if you don't want to include jQuery/SPServices in your overhead.

Comment: Thank you @Colin, I like SPServices and your solution. But I am discovering ASP.NET and SharePoint's built-in possibilities in order to (maybe) improve or (at least) evaluate it. I have used listdata.svc and Client Object Model. I think I'll use more SPServices.

But the question remains. What have I to do to enable a native asp.net javascript proxy for my web services.